# php path multiple arrays pathfinding

Tags: php, arrays, path-finding

I'm working on game that involves going from location to location on a map via predefined routes.
I have an array that contains every location on the map, and which locations that are connected to that location.

So, say I start at location 1, and want to go to location 8, I might have to go through locations 3 and 7 to get to 8.

Here is the array:

```
$location[1]=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$location[2]=array(1,3,7);
$location[3]=array(1,2,4,11);
$location[4]=array(1,3,5);
$location[5]=array(1,4,6,16);
$location[6]=array(1,5,17);
$location[7]=array(1,2,23);
$location[8]=array(9,10,11);
$location[9]=array(8,10,11);
$location[10]=array(8,9,11);
$location[11]=array(8,9,10,3);
$location[12]=array(13,14,16);
$location[13]=array(12,14);
$location[14]=array(12,13,16);
$location[15]=array(16);
$location[16]=array(12,14,5);
$location[17]=array(18,20,6);
$location[18]=array(17,19);
$location[19]=array(18);
$location[20]=array(17);
$location[21]=array(22,23);
$location[22]=array(21,23);
$location[23]=array(21,22,7);
```

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to come up with a pathfinding algorithm for this.

Comment: See [wikipedia page on graph traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal#Graph_traversal_algorithms) for some pointers.

Comment: Check out this Q&A on gamedev: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-path-finding-algorithms-are-there

Comment: Hopefully those suggestions can help get you started. I think as a Stack Overflow question, you'll need to narrow this down quite a bit to get it out of "Too Broad" territory. I mean, there are entire books about this, you know?

Comment: It does seem from your data that the path from 1 to 8 actually goes through 3 and **11**, not 3 and 7

Comment: Thanks all. Those links did help. They lead me to the dijkstra algorithm, and I found a php implementation that does the job.